# How to use eval in karate?

Tags: karate

I already gone through the karate documentation and tried below code:

```
 * eval if (nearby.content[?(@.title == 'Nearby Malls & Restaurants')] == '#notnull') karate.call(* def nearByMallsRestraurants = get nearby.content[?(@.title == 'Nearby Malls & Restaurants')].items[?(@.name)])
```

But its throwing error.I am trying to extract all Nearby Malls & Restaurants names if Nearby Places and Landmarks Array contains Nearby Malls & Restaurant.Also if possible can you please tell me how to use `collection.sort` to get sorted Nearby Malls name.

My json looks like :

```
"nearby": {
        "title": "Nearby Places and Landmarks",
        "content": [
          {
            "title": "Nearby Malls & Restaurants",
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "Forum Mall, Koramangala",
                "distance": 1.8
              },
              {
                "name": "Eggzotic",
                "distance": 2.4
              },
              {
                "name": "Kerala Pavilion Restaurant",
                "distance": 2.4
              },
              {
                "name": "New Shanthi Nagar",
                "distance": 2.5
              },
              {
                "name": "Venus Biryani",
                "distance": 2.8
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "title": "Closest Airport, Railway Station & Bus Stand",
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "Madiwala Ayyappa Temple Bus Stop",
                "distance": 2.1
              },
              {
                "name": "Kalasipalyam Bus Stand",
                "distance": 5.7
              },
              {
                "name": "Bangalore Cantonment Railway Station",
                "distance": 6.5
              },
              {
                "name": "Kempegowda/ Majestic bus station",
                "distance": 7
              },
              {
                "name": "KSR Bengaluru City Railway Station",
                "distance": 7.5
              },
              {
                "name": "KR Puram Railway Station",
                "distance": 8.5
              },
              {
                "name": "KSRTC Mysore Road Satellite Bus Stop",
                "distance": 9
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note - JsonPath is not JS and you are mixing things here. My advice is don't over-complicate things and split it into multiple steps. This should answer all your questions, including a sort:

```
* def malls = $nearby.content[?(@.title=='Nearby Malls & Restaurants')]
* def names = $malls..name
* def Collections = Java.type('java.util.Collections')
* eval Collections.sort(names)
* print names
```

output:

```
[
  "Eggzotic",
  "Forum Mall, Koramangala",
  "Kerala Pavilion Restaurant",
  "New Shanthi Nagar",
  "Venus Biryani"
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter.But I am trying to extract all ```Nearby Malls & Restaurants``` names only if ```Nearby Places and Landmarks``` contains ```Nearby Malls & Restaurants``` json as ```Nearby Malls & Restaurants``` is not mandatory.

Comment: @GauravKinra which is absolutely fine, did you try it ? add this line and see what happens if you don't have malls: `* eval if (names.length == 0) karate.log('no malls found')`

Comment: Hi Peter, need a small help related to this only right now i have an api which return  data ```price": {
"pretax_price": 7002.84,
"rack_rate": 8140.82,
"wallet_deductable_amount": 0,
"voucher_amount": 0,
"total_discount_percent": 92.75,
"net_payable_amount": 4131.68,
}```.Now what i am trying to do is  ```* def pretax =price.pretax_price``` should be called only if ```* def valueFromDB == true``` where ```valueFromDB``` is coming from DB.

Comment: @GauravKinra please do this in a new question please.